# Create binary (family) tree from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-tree

I have to write some methods for family binary tree, but I'm stuck on initializing the tree itself, can somebody help me with it / point to some help?

```
class FamilyTree:

    class Node:
        def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
            self.data = data
            self.left = left
            self.right = right
    class Queue:
        def __init__(self):
            self.pole = []
        def enqueue(self, data):
            self.pole.append(data)
        def dequeue(self):
            if self.is_empty():
                return None
            return self.pole.pop(0)
        def is_empty(self):
            return self.pole==[]
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        ...
```

the file looks like this (structure: parent-child):

> Pre-Vla
>  Mir-Bol
>  Pre-Kaz
>   Bra-Ras
>  Dra-Lub
>  Lud-Moj
>   Sva-Mir
>  Sta-Pre
>  Jar-Sta
>   Kaz-Pra
>  Sva-Jar
>  Vla-Boh
>   Jar-Lud
>  Boh-Lad
>  Vla-Sve
>   Boh-Vla
>  Mir-Boh
>  Bol-Dra
>   Bol-Bra

I somehow need to parse it in some appropriate structure (dict, touple?) and then make a tree from it. It's a binary tree, so one parent has 2 children at most.

Comment: Your tree has two parents for the same child: Boh. So this is not a tree. Do you want validation too?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit twisted way to create a (not necessarily binary) tree from your file. The tree is actually stored in a dictionary with father as keys and a list of children as values.

```
from collections import defaultdict

nodes = []
with open('tree.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for line in content:
        for node in line.split('-'):
            nodes.append(node.rstrip()) 

bTree = defaultdict(list)
for father, children in zip(nodes[0::2], nodes[1::2]):
    print 'Inserting (' + father + ', ' + children + ')'
    bTree[father].append(children)
print(bTree)
```

Depending on what you need to do, that might do the trick and be easier to implement than a tree class.

Answer (score 0):

This creates a binary tree from your file.
It raises an exception for the file example that you supplied since some of the children there have two parents, so that's not a valid tree.

(I named your file "parent_child.txt" and saved it where the code is saved.)

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __str__(self):
        return self.str_tree()

    def str_tree(self, level=0):
        tree = "{space}{data}\n".format(space="  " * level, data=str(self.data))
        if self.left is not None:
            tree += self.left.str_tree(level + 1)
        if self.right is not None:
            tree += self.right.str_tree(level + 1)
        return tree

    def add_child(self, child):
        if self.left is None:
            self.left = child
        elif self.right is None:
            self.right = child
        else:
            raise Exception("Node {} already has two children".format(self.data))

class FamilyTree(object):
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.root = self.generate_tree_from_file(file_name)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.root)

    @staticmethod
    def generate_tree_from_file(file_name):
        data_to_node = {}
        has_parent = set()
        with open(file_name) as file_handle:
            for line in file_handle:
                line = line.rstrip('\n')
                parent, child = line.split("-")
                child_node = get_or_create(data_to_node, child)
                parent_node = get_or_create(data_to_node, parent)
                if child in has_parent:
                    raise Exception("Multiple parents for child {}".format(child))
                has_parent.add(child)
                parent_node.add_child(child_node)

        no_parent = data_to_node.viewkeys() - has_parent
        if len(no_parent) > 1:
            raise Exception("The tree has more than one root: {}".format(", ".join(no_parent)))
        return data_to_node[no_parent.pop()]

def get_or_create(data_to_node, data):
    if data in data_to_node:
        return data_to_node[data]
    data_to_node[data] = Node(data)
    return data_to_node[data]

if "__main__" == __name__:
    print(FamilyTree("parent_child.txt"))
```

It works for this file where each child has a single parent:

```
Pre-Vla
Mir-Bol
Pre-Kaz
Bra-Ras
Dra-Lub
Lud-Moj
Sva-Mir
Sta-Pre
Jar-Sta
Kaz-Pra
Sva-Jar
Vla-Boh
Jar-Lud
Boh-Lad
Vla-Sve
Boh-Vla2
Mir-Boh2
Bol-Dra
Bol-Bra
```